# No value is added into the column

Tags: postgresql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to find the difference between the Unix seconds and adding into the existing null column but the results are not added into the column. As I am new I can't figure it out.

```
INSERT INTO "Operation"(minutes)
select (departure_unix_seconds - arrival_unix_seconds)/60  As Difference 
from public."Operation";
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new record using INSERT or update a current record using UPDATE?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Thank you for the reply.  I am doing this difference operation using select and the results are to added as a new column to the existing table. In any way will be fine not just with insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a column in your table called "minutes" , and you want to update that column , here is the syntax:

```
update public."Operation"
set minutes = (departure_unix_seconds - arrival_unix_seconds)/60
```

however usually when a column value depends on other column(s) ,It's better to be implemented as "generated column":

```
alter table Operation
add column minutes generated always as (departure_unix_seconds - arrival_unix_seconds)/60 stored;
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear idea. What can be done to get the result in minutes and seconds, now I can only see the minutes in integer format.

Comment: @Aravinth that would be another question , which you can ask as a new question in stackoverflow